# Python to send a command through another process, wait for process to terminate, and then reboot system?

Tags: python, debian

I'm running a Minecraft server for my friends and I off of a Raspberry Pi. Aside from lag (Due to my internet, not the hardware) the server runs smoothly, however, my Pi wants to shut off every so often (If the server console crashes, or if screen decides to close that session, etc...). What I want to do is create a python script that runs at Midnight and Noon every day to issue a few commands through the server console and to the pi itself.

The server console is accessed through `screen -r Minecraft` so I can close an SSH session and leave the server running. If the server is not running, it can be started with `./minecraft.sh`.

Heres essentially what I want to do: (Sorry, I know very little python aside from what I need to navigate the pi console) (I am more familiar with C# so I'm sorry if my code more resembles that instead of Python)
Note: Commands issued into the server console screen -r minecraft do not require quotes around non-command text I.E. Say Words will send Words to game chat, but Say "Words" will send "Words" to game chat.

```
//SafeShutDown.py
//This code is in no way executable. I just typed it out as an outline. A lot is wrong with it I'm assuming.

Loop A;
If dateTime.Now == 12:00 or dateTime.Now == 24:00 { 
    screen -r Minecraft
    say Server saving... //In minecraft console. Announces to players
    autosave all //In minecraft console. Plugin to save the world
    say Server is restarting in 1 minute. Please wait //In Minecraft console
    wait 60s //In python
    stop //Command to send within the process "Minecraft" to shutdown server

    wait for process "Screen -r Minecraft" to terminate //This is what I need help with
    reboot
Else { Go To A;}

// Other scripts here that starts at boot to run ./minecraft.sh and ./SafeShutDown.py from /home/Minecraft.
```

I have tried getting scripts to run at boot to no avail. Minecraft.sh is supposed to run at boot so if it crashes will still run (Minecraft.sh starts server under screen -r Minecraft so I can get to it later)

Edit: Spelling, C# explanation, better code.
Edit: Descriptors of Minecraft commands, added announcements and save state.

Comment: Well, you can  write script which starts subprocess.Popen(['your', 'server', 'comand']) every 12 hours

Comment: This kind of simple logic can be easily done using cron instead of python. Have you thought about using cron? The killing part is also quite simple with bash scripting. `pkill -f minecraft`

Comment: @ThuYeinTun yes that would work, however, I want to run the stop command on the server rather than just killing the process. I want all the saving stuff to run. And I would need to announce in game chat that the shutdown is happening.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev would that work like `subprocess.Popen(screen -r Minecraft; stop);` and then wait for process `screen -r Minecraft` to terminate to reboot the pi? Sorry, I cannot test anything on my Pi right now because it is down and won't automatically go back up for some reason, so I can't SSH into it as I normally would.

Comment: @Gagewillson I made example, it is related to win, can do same in Unix, it is easier to make several commands in row in Unix:                                          import  subprocess
encoding = 'latin1'
p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
cmds = []
cmds.append("cd C:\\Users\LOL\\Desktop\\ \n")
cmds.append("dir \n")
cmds.append("ping 127.0.0.1 \n")
cmds.append("ping 127.0.0.2 \n")
for cmd in cmds:
    p.stdin.write(cmd.encode('utf-8'))
p.stdin.close()
print(p.stdout.read().decode('ansi'))

Comment: @Gagewillson was the example usefull for you?